# Как получить выделенный текст из textarea (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Добрый день уважаемые посетители hashcode.
Сегодня я столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

```
function getSel() {
if (window.getSelection) {
    return window.getSelection();
} else if (document.getSelection) {
    return document.getSelection();
} else if (document.selection) {
    return document.selection.createRange().text;
} else return;
```

}

Функция getSel() возвращает только выделенный текст со страницы, но не возвращает выделенный текст из элементов textarea, input и т.п. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы она возвращала выделенный текст и из них.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пользуюсь таким вот кодом:

```
// Флаги для определения браузеров
var uagent    = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_safari = ( (uagent.indexOf('safari') != -1) || (navigator.vendor == "Apple Computer, Inc.") );
var is_ie     = ( (uagent.indexOf('msie') != -1) && (!is_opera) && (!is_safari) && (!is_webtv) );
var is_ie4    = ( (is_ie) && (uagent.indexOf("msie 4.") != -1) );
var is_moz    = (navigator.product == 'Gecko');
var is_ns     = ( (uagent.indexOf('compatible') == -1) && (uagent.indexOf('mozilla') != -1) && (!is_opera) && (!is_webtv) && (!is_safari) );
var is_ns4    = ( (is_ns) && (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) == 4) );
var is_opera  = (uagent.indexOf('opera') != -1);  
var is_kon    = (uagent.indexOf('konqueror') != -1);
var is_webtv  = (uagent.indexOf('webtv') != -1);

var is_win    =  ( (uagent.indexOf("win") != -1) || (uagent.indexOf("16bit") !=- 1) );
var is_mac    = ( (uagent.indexOf("mac") != -1) || (navigator.vendor == "Apple Computer, Inc.") );
var ua_vers   = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);

// Сама функция
function getSelection( textarea )
{
    var selection = null;
    if ((ua_vers >= 4) && is_ie && is_win) {
        if (textarea.isTextEdit) {
            textarea.focus();
            var sel = document.selection;
            var rng = sel.createRange();
            rng.collapse;
            if((sel.type == "Text" || sel.type == "None") && rng != null)
                selection = rng.text;
        }
    } else if (typeof(textarea.selectionEnd) != "undefined" ) { 
        selection = (textarea.value).substring(textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd);
    }
    return selection;
}
```

Взял его в свое время из одного из форумовских скриптов.

Comment: getSelection(textarea) не совсем понял что в textarea постить? id? или значение

Comment: Сам элемент. Если есть id, то

    getSelection( document.getElementById('ta') );

Answer (score 3):

Посмотри [ответ на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript). Даже если английский проблема - не беда, смотреть можно сразу на код в ответе. (ниже главного ответа есть примеры для организации кроссбраузерности)