# Как получить выделеный текст из textarea

Tags: jquery

[Как получить выделенный текст из textarea (JavaScript)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/110750/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-textarea-javascript)

собственно сделал как в ответе, к выше приведёному вопросу. Но не получаеться в файрефоксе возвращает `null` хотелось бы реализацию на jQuery. По гуглив такой не нашёл, логика в принципе проста определить начало выделеной области и конец, и обрезав текст получить выделенный фрагмент. Задача в принципе тривиальная и не ужели нет в jQuery подобной функции?

p.s. Я php программист по этому в jQuery не силён.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Offtop] Чистый javscript:

```js
function gettext(area) {
  // all and IE9+
  if ('selectionStart' in area) {
    var len = area.value.length,
    sp = Math.min(area.selectionStart, len), // IE bug
    ep = Math.min(area.selectionEnd, len); // IE bug

    return area.value.substring(sp, ep);
  } 

  // IE9-
  if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    area.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    return sel.text;
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="button" value="Жми" onclick="alert('Выделенный текст: \'' + gettext(document.getElementById('myText')) + '\'');return false;"></div>
<textarea rows="10" cols="80" id="myText"></textarea>
```

Comment: решил вопрос этим https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection и функцией `getSelection` и вроде всё работает! но всё равно спасибо.

Comment: интересная конструкция `if ('selectionStart' in area)` поясните что это значит

Comment: @MaximPro, проверяет есть ли свойство с именем `selectionStart` в объекте на который указывает переменная `area` (в данном случае в `textarea`).

Comment: ага ясно, спасибо