# Редактировать выделенный текст

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Мне надо, чтобы при нажатии shift+P в textarea выделенный текст оборачивался в теги p. То есть

```
<p>Выделеный текст</p>
```

А если выделенного текста нет, то просто на место курсора вставить

```
<p></p>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить выделенный текст из textarea (JavaScript)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/110750/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-textarea-javascript)

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, тут не textarea.

Comment: @OlexijHavryshkiv тут где? в этом вопросе? или в старом который я скинул как уже существующий?

Comment: В этом вопросе так написано `Мне надо, чтобы при нажатии shift+P в textarea`, А это заголовок другого `Как получить выделенный текст из textarea (JavaScript)`, и где нет `textarea` ? у обеих то же самое .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда то искал подобную вещь, нашел вот такую реализацию:

```
function wrapText(elementID, openTag, closeTag) {
    var textArea = $('#' + elementID);
    var len = textArea.val().length;
    var start = textArea[0].selectionStart;
    var end = textArea[0].selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
    var replacement = openTag + selectedText + closeTag;
    textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
}
```

И потом вызываете при хоткее вашем:

```
wrapText("input-id", "<p>", "</p>");
```

Чтобы всё это делалось хоткеем нужно подулючить библиотеку [jquery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)
Для вызова хоткея пишите вот так:

```
$('#input-id').on('keydown', null, 'Shift+p', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    wrapText("input-id", "<p>", "</p>");
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую

Comment: @OlexijHavryshkiv дополнил ответ, всё работает, так что если что-то не отработает пишите

Comment: усе работает спасибо